# Rebase/copy all missing commits from one branch on top of current branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

ok, this looks so simple but I can't find an easy solution. Let's say there are two branches:

```
a - b - c - d - e - f <current_branch>
         \
          g - h - i <temp_branch>
```

I simply want all missing commits in `<temp_branch>` to be on top of `<current_branch>` without touching `<temp_branch>` and without merge commit:

```
a - b - c - d - e - f - g' - h' - i' <current_branch>
         \
          g - h - i <temp_branch>
```

What didn't work:

- `git rebase` : I could first rebase `<temp_branch>` on top of `<current_branch>` and merge back fast-forward. But that's not what I want and it is too complicated.
- `git cherry-pick` : if there is no automatic way, manually looking up the commit-range is required

A simple one-liner would be great, like

```
git rebase --reverse-order temp_branch HEAD
```

Or some other command I don't know of?

Comment: By "missing commits", do you mean that you *do* want to skip otherwise-identical commits the way `git rebase` would?

Comment: that would be a nice-to-have but is not required. I know that the commits are not diff-identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way:

```
$ git status  # just to make sure you're on the current branch :-)
```

Now that you know for sure you're on current_branch:

```
$ git cherry-pick HEAD..temp_branch
```

which relies on `cherry-pick`'s internal sequencing to do them in the right order, but won't skip patch-equivalent commits.

The slightly harder way that skips patch-identical commits:

```
$ git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse --topo-order \
    --right-only --cherry-pick HEAD...temp_branch)
```

or the same with `--left-only` and `temp_branch...HEAD` (these should be precisely the same).

(I have not tested either one, but `git rebase --interactive` uses:

```
git rev-list $merges_option --format="%m%H ${format:-%s}" \
    --reverse --left-right --topo-order \
    $revisions ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision} | \
    sed -n "s/^>//p" | ...
```

where `$merges_option` is `--no-merges --cherry-pick`, `$revisions` is `$upstream...$orig_head` where those are the obvious, and `$restrict_revision` is via `--fork-point` if specified).  The `sed` command deletes the right-side commits.  You may want an explicit `--no-merges` as well, though this is not needed for the illustrated case.)

Comment: `git cherry-pick ..temp_branch` ! That's what I was looking for. Didn't know you can specify the commit differences like that not only for `log` but also for `cherry-pick` (and probably everywhere else). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use rebase in this way (having `current_branch` checked out):

```
git reset --hard temp_branch && git rebase ORIG_HEAD
```

which automatically skips redundant commits.

Credits go to my colleague [Michael Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5002783), who came up with that idea.